# java get user to input query via console

Tags: java, database, jdbc, input, alignment

I'm working on a simple query database thing for a h2 table using jdbc.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class program {

    public static void main(String a)
            throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2://C:/Users/Office/Desktop/DED/files/db/dedserver", "sa", "");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();    


        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(a);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int a1 = 1; a1 <= columnsNumber; a1++) {

            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(a1);
            System.out.printf(columnName);

            int strLength1 = columnName.length();
            for(int c = 0; c+strLength1 <= 15;  c++){

                System.out.printf(" ");

            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n");

            while (rs.next()) {

                    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                        System.out.printf(columnValue);

                        int strLength = columnValue.length();
                        for(int b = 0; b+strLength <= 15;  b++){

                            System.out.printf(" ");

                        }

                    }

                System.out.println("");
            }

        conn.close();
    }

}
```

I have two questions but one main one.

The main one is, how do I get it so when the program is run the user has to enter a string of text that will be defined as "a" and then used as the query. If the query fails it should print back a user friendly message and it also needs to detect stuff like if the user types "help" then something else will show up. What has to be done for that?

The other question is how do I align the data results so it is all formatted nicely in a table and all aligned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your main question:

You can do this code to get the query from the console input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = scanner.nextLine(); // Stores the input from the console to this variable
```

and to see if your user types "help", enter this code:

```
if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
    // What ever you want here
 }
```

Comment: for the help thing i get this error "Cannot invoke trim() on the primitive type boolean"

Comment: Remove the `trim()` then. It is not compulsory, but trims any extra space off.